# Replacing data in database from a csv file 

Tags: c#, database, csv

I am creating a Windows based application to read csv file and display in datagridview. The csv file consist of item_no and stock.

I have two buttons, add data and replace data.

With add data, same item_no stock get added and it is then inserted into database. In database, stock get added with the existing stock of particular item_no.

With the replace data, same item_no stock get added and it is then replace with the stock of item_no in database.

I am able to add the stock in database but I can't replace the stock in the database.

Here is my code to replace data which is more likely same as add stock,

```
try
   {

     //we need to copy the data from datagridview into data table
     DataTable dtable = new DataTable();

     dtable.TableName = "Product";

     foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
     {
        dtable.Columns.Add(col.DataPropertyName, col.ValueType);
     }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

            {

                if (row.IsNewRow)

                    continue;



                DataRow dtRow = dtable.NewRow();



                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)

                    dtRow[i] = (row.Cells[i].Value == null ? DBNull.Value : row.Cells[i].Value);



                dtable.Rows.Add(dtRow);

            }



            foreach (DataRow dr in dtable.Rows)

            {

                string itemNo = null;

                string itemName = null;

                double cost = 0.00;

                double price = 0.00;

                double Stock = 0.00;

                int dept = 1;

                double tax1 = 0;

                double tax2 = 0;

                double BulkPrize = 0.00;

                double BulkQty = 0.00;

             //   double finalStock = 0.00;

                itemNo = Convert.ToString(dr[0]);



                if (dr[1] != DBNull.Value)

                    itemName = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);





                if (dr[2] != DBNull.Value)

                    price = Convert.ToDouble(dr[2]);





                if (dr[3] != DBNull.Value)

                    cost = Convert.ToDouble(dr[3]);



                Stock = Convert.ToDouble(dr[4]);

               // finalStock = finalStock + Stock;



                if (dr[5] != DBNull.Value)

                    dept = Convert.ToInt32(dr[5]);



                if (dr[6] != DBNull.Value)

                    tax1 = Convert.ToDouble(dr[6]);



                if (dr[7] != DBNull.Value)

                    tax2 = Convert.ToDouble(dr[7]);



                string sql_select = "select count(*) from PRODUCTS where item_no= '" + itemNo + "'";

                SqlCommand cmdCheckPmk = new SqlCommand(sql_select, Class1.conn);



                int selectItemNo = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCheckPmk.ExecuteScalar());



                if (selectItemNo != 0)

                {

                    string sql_update = "update PRODUCTS set item_stock=+'" + Stock + "' where item_no= '" + itemNo + "'";

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql_update, Class1.conn);

                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();



                }

                else

                {

                    SqlCommand cmd11 = new SqlCommand("insert into PRODUCTS(item_no,item_name,price,cost,item_stock,dept_id,tax_rate1,tax_rate2,bulk_price,bulk_qty) values ('" + itemNo + "','" + itemName + "'," + price + "," + cost + "," + Stock + ",'" + dept + "','" + tax1 + "','" + tax2 + "'," + BulkPrize +"," + BulkQty +") ", Class1.conn);

                    cmd11.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }



            MessageBox.Show("Data Replace Successfully ..!!", "Congrats", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }

        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException exe)

        {

            if (exe.Number == 547)

            {

                MessageBox.Show("Add Department in Corner Store First..!!", "Add Department in Corner Store", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }

            else

            {

                MessageBox.Show(exe.Message, "Error in replace - Option 3 Insert/Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }

        }

    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Rushabh

Comment: I see that others have mentioned this on some of your previous questions, but I'll mention it again.  You would probably get more assistance if you accepted some answers.  If someone provides an answer that is useful, click the check box beside it.

Comment: Do you know how to accept an answer? You still haven't accepted the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570172/retrieve-value-from-csv-file-and-replace-it-in-database-in-c which you posted earlier today. At some point people are going to stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right

```
string sql_update = "update PRODUCTS set item_stock=+'" + Stock + "' where item_no= '" + itemNo + "'";
```

I think you want (**try this**)

```
string sql_update = "update PRODUCTS set item_stock='" + Stock + "' where item_no= '" + itemNo + "'";
```

Also I'm not sure if your item_no is an `int` or not, if it is an `int` you need

```
string sql_update = "update PRODUCTS set item_stock='" + Stock + "' where item_no = " + itemNo ;
```

Comment: item_no is string. I need to add stock and then replace final stock value with the value in database